# PyCharm does not support Django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have PyCharm Community Edition 2017.

I'm learning django.
My PyCharm does not autocomplete django methods and in templates I dont have formatting.

Why application for python does not support this ?
Is this only for $$$ in PyCharm ??

Comment: Yes, it's only in Professional version of PyCharm.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is only Django support is included only in Professional version of PyCharm.

You can view [**the difference**](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) between Community and Professional Editions.